# How to check if the number of lines in the file equal the number of characters in each of the lines?

Tags: python

Reads the specified file and treats its contents as a list of strings (one per line).
Checks for the following conditions in the input file:

The file must exist and be available for reading. In other words, the call to open should not raise an exception.

The file must contain between 3 and 10 lines of text. That is, 3 is the minimum acceptable number of lines, and 10 is the maximum number of lines.

All lines must contain exactly the same number of characters.

Each line must contain between 3 and 10 characters. That is, 3 is the minimum acceptable number of characters, and 10 is the maximum. The number of characters per line does NOT have to equal the number of lines in the file.

The only acceptable characters are `'x'`, `'X'`, `'y'`, `'Y'`, and `'_'`.

```
correct_string = False
while correct_string is False:

    string = input("Enter a string? ")
    if len(string) != len(string):
        print("Error: string must have the same number of characters.")
    else:
        incorrect_char = False
        for i in string:
            if i != "X" and i != "x" and i != 'Y' and i != 'y' and i != "_":
                incorrect_char = True
        if incorrect_char is False:
            correct_string = True
        else:
            print("Invalid Character. Contains characters other than 'X', 'x', 'Y' 'y',and '_'")
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How to check if the number of lines in the file equal the number of characters in each of the lines? @whatsisname

Comment: @user88453 are you trying to determine if the file represents a square matrix?

Comment: yes exactly @MichaelT

Answer (score 2):

This code checks to see if  the number of lines in the file equals the number of characters in each of the lines. It does not check any of the other criteria, as they aren't part of the question.

```
with open('input.txt') as in_file:
  lines = [ line.rstrip('\n') for line in in_file]

if any( len(line) != len(lines) for line in lines):
  print "NOT SQUARE!"
else:
  print "SQUARE!"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you're asking and return a list if valid. If not, it will raise an exception - you can customize as required.

```
def load_file(filename):

    valid_chars = set('xXyY_')
    min_len = 3
    max_len = 10
    data = []

    # load the file
    with open(filename) as f:
        num_rows = 0
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()
            print line, len(line)
            num_rows += 1
            # load validation
            if num_rows > max_len:
                raise Exception('Max rows exceeded')
            if len(line) > max_len:
                raise Exception('Max columns exceeded')
            if not set(line) <= valid_chars:
                print set(line), valid_chars
                raise Exception('Invalid input')
            data.append(line)

    if num_rows < min_len:
        raise Exception('Not enough rows')

    # validate row length
    if any( len(line) <> num_rows for line in data):
        raise Exception('Invalid row length')

    return data
```

To call:

```
>>> load_file('test.txt')
['xxx', 'xYx', 'xXx']
```

You can tweak as needed. Hope this helps.